# Populating a UITableView with JSON data

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to iOS and am having trouble getting my JSON data from my server to my UITableView.

The JSON data is as follows:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"cali.mp4","url":"http://10.0.0.3/videos/cali.mp4"},{"id":2,"name":"test","url":"http://10.0.0.3/videos/allVideos.php"}]
```

Parse JSON data:

```
-(void)parseVideoJSON:(NSData*)data 
{
    NSError* error;
    id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

    if (result == nil)
   {
      NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON:\n%@",error.userInfo);
      return;
   }

   if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
   {
      NSArray* videoArray = (NSArray*)result;
      NSLog(@"Found %lu new videos", (unsigned long)[videoArray count]);

       for (NSDictionary* video in videoArray){
          Video* videoData = [[Video alloc] init];
          videoData.name = [video objectForKey:@"name"];
          videoData.url = [video objectForKey:@"url"];
       }
   }
}
```

And my tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    VideoCell *cell = (VideoCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"VideoCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Video* v = [self.listVideos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    // Configure the cell...
    cell.videoName.text = v.name;
    cell.videoURL.text = v.url;
    return cell;
}
```

I am using the same methods for core data and its working perfectly, any help would be greatly appreciated =)

Comment: Did you have a question?  You've presented no problem, just code.

Comment: reload your table view in json parsing method

Comment: Sorry, my question basically the UITableView is not getting populated with the data from my server and have used the same method for another class i have, "student" which populates the tableview with student data and saves it to core data. Video on the other hand does not use core data, i wish to download the data and populate the table with my JSON data. I hope that made sense.

Comment: Have you done any debugging at all??  Based on your (non)description the JSON could be nil, it could be a dictionary, anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `numberOfRowsInSection` method as:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.listVideos count];
}
```

in your parse method while parsing json data add new data into `self.listVideos` and reload tableview after parsing like this:

```
for (NSDictionary* video in videoArray) {
    Video* videoData = [[Video alloc] init];
    videoData.name = [video objectForKey:@"name"];
    videoData.url = [video objectForKey:@"url"];
    [self.listVideos addObject:videoData];
}
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Thank you! i was reloading the table previously inside the for loop=)

Comment: you just need to reload once after completing parsing..

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add the data to array

```
for (NSDictionary* video in videoArray)
{
   Video* videoData = [[Video alloc] init];
   videoData.name = [video objectForKey:@"name"];
   videoData.url = [video objectForKey:@"url"];
   [self.listVideos addObject:videoData];
}
```

Comment: I tried that and i still get     2014-05-30 20:58:09.226 TutorHelper[347:60b] Last udpate was: 1401445719.983379
2014-05-30 20:58:10.437 TutorHelper[347:60b] Found 2 new videos.          The UITableView is still empty

Answer (score 0):

reload your tableview

```
for (NSDictionary* video in videoArray) {
    Video* videoData = [[Video alloc] init];
    videoData.name = [video objectForKey:@"name"];
    videoData.url = [video objectForKey:@"url"];
    [self.listVideos addObject:videoData];
}
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you instantiated `self.listVideos`?

```
self.listVideos = [NSMutableArray new]; 

for (NSDictionary* video in videoArray){
         Video* videoData = [Video new];
         videoData.name = video[@"name"];
         videoData.url = video[@"url"];
         [self.listVideos addObject:videoData];
}
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Make sure you add this method from `UITableViewDataSource`:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.listVideos count];
}
```